# Raw 2D arrays as function parameters in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, embedded, keil

Are raw arrays unsafe to use in C++ considering there are libraries such as `std::array` and `std::vector`? For embedded systems, using `std::vector` I believe may not be efficient particularly when there are several functions to implement and there's some heavy mathematical algorithms inside each function.
`std::array` isn't supported in the IDE I am working in. Is there any other way around raw arrays or they are fine to use? Or perhaps wrap arrays in a class?

Below is an example of how I am implementing this:

`main.cpp`

```
#include "file.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

   funcClass func_class;

   func_class.divide();
   func_class.returnValue = func_class.multiply(func_class.vector);
```

`file.h`

```
#ifndef file_hpp
#define file_hpp

 class funcClass{

   public:

   static const double a;
   static const double b;
   static const double c;

   double var1, var2, var3;


   void divide();

   double (*multiply(double answer[4][1]))[1];
   double vector[4][1];
   double (*returnValue)[1];


 }; 

#endif /* file_hpp */
```

`file.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include "file.hpp"

 const double funcClass::a = 5.5;    //constants
 const double funcClass::b = 4.4;
 const double funcClass::c = 14.4;

 funcClass::funcClass(){          //constructor for initializing variables

   var1 = 10.5;
   var2 = 20.5;
   var3 = 100.0;

 }

 void divide(){

    // some mathematical algorithms


 }


 double (*funcClass::multiply(double answer[4][1]))[1]{

 //.......

 answer[0][0] = 30.5;
 answer[1][0] = 31.6;
 answer[2][0] = 10.5;
 answer[3][0] = 21.6;


  return answer;
 }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with keil, but can you implement your own `array`? It's not like its difficult. BTW judging by your use of `stdio.h` and `cmath`, you might very well just write C instead

Comment: Also, this feels off-topic to me, you might want to post at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: If your IDE doesn't support `std::array`, write your code using a simple editor.

Comment: @juanchopanza what do you mean by simple editor here? Do you think bounds is the issue with raw arrays?

Comment: The bigger problem with C-array IMO is the ugly syntax `double (*multiply(double answer[4][1]))[1];` (note that your argument is "wrong" as `4` might be any size, you should have passed the argument by reference to avoid that).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you always avoid STL containers in embedded systems. Compilers have improved over the years, but may still spew all kinds of inefficient crap when you use these containers. What I do is to kill everything called heap in the linker script, then see if it links after that. If not, the libraries are crap and cannot be used. After that, just check the map file - did the compiler create a local array? Ok then these might be safe (but not portable) to use. If it spewed some random chunk of binary goo, you can't use STL either. Summary: it is much much safer to use raw arrays.

Comment: @PasserBy when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat noted, thanks

Comment: @Lundin Even if a container is just a wrapper around a raw array?

Comment: @PasserBy Obviously it will always be a wrapper in some meaning, because STL comes with features of diverse usefulness as overhead. With a debugger, you should be able to tell how the actual data is allocated though. The various features provided by STL are usually not enough to motivate the use of such containers in embedded systems - the more useful ones such as `::iterator` with `begin()` and `end()` tend to create less efficient code than a raw loop on many compilers. Likely `array` will perform much better than `vector`.

Comment: Usually this boils down to how resource-constrained your target is. For microcontrollers like Cortex M or smaller, I would avoid STL and various other parts of C++.

Comment: @Lundin I'll remember that, that's pretty interesting

Answer (score 1):

2D arrays are allowed per C++ standard from the beginning of C++ to the last (and upcoming version), so you can use them. But that's not the nicer part of the language, and you must be prepared to control twice your code. If you can, `std::array` (fixed size) and `std::vector` (variable size) are much more programmer friendly. But at the very end, they are implemented through raw arrays and raw pointers...

My advice, is that it is legitimate to use raw arrays (including 2D arrays) if you know why in your use case they are better suited than standard containers, but it would certainly be better to wrap them in higher level classes if is makes sense, or simply typedefs if it is enough to keep the high program architecture clean.

Said differently: if in doubt, stick to standard containers, your life will be easier; but raw 2D arrays are not forbidden.

Comment: Fair enough. The issue with `std::array` is that it is not supported in the IDE I am working in. As for `std::vector`, I think it is not ideal for embedded systems particularly when your program isn't small. 


Can you give a small demonstration of how you would go about wrapping arrays in a class?

Comment: @Doej This is still the main problem with C++ in embedded systems: most C++ compilers on the market are crap. Keil doesn't exactly have a good reputation and they had 6 years now, you'd think they would at least have implemented partial support for C++11.

Comment: @Doej: The idea is to identify the (high level) operations you need to do on the arrays, and code them as methods on a class hiding the 2D array complexity to the remaining of the program, mainly the allocation/deallocation part if relevant. As I do not know your use cases I cannot give a good example. And if you have neither dynamic allocation nor clear use case methods, typedef is probably enough.

Comment: @Lundin yeah, which is very annoying. But I can wrap arrays around class using templates as an alternative to `std::array` which I can't use as it's not recognized by the IDE?

Comment: @SergeBallesta So you mean instead of using raw arrays, wrap them around a class using templates?